# ERROR in Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js): in angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, webpack, sass

i was using the windows 10 in my pc , and when i run the projects it works good .

but i change my operation system to linux ubntu afer that when i need to run the my project it show me this errors :

```
ERROR in ./src/styles.scss (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-3!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--17-1!./src/styles.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: File to import not found or unreadable: ./stylings/base/color.scss.
        on line 1 of src/stylings/main.scss
        from line 6 of src/styles.scss
>> @import "./stylings/base/color.scss";

   ^

ERROR in Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: overloaded function `rgba` given wrong number of arguments
        on line 8 of src/app/shared/components/user-info/icon-user-info/icon-user-info.component.scss
       color: rgba(var(--color-primary));

   ---------------^
```

i using these commands for solve this pproblem :

`npm install` , `npm install postcss-loader` but it not worked and when i serve my project it show me this error .

whats the problem ? how can i sovle this problem ????

Comment: it looks like the signature of `rgba()` is different between the Windows and Linux, try checking which versions you have in each OS